# How can i check bandwidth usage in webrtc?

Tags: webrtc, bandwidth

I would like to check bandwidth usage in my webrtc application, to find out the threshold at which sound and video are asynchronous.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can do this with chrome://webrtc-internals.

Comment: @ Benjamin Trent, thanks, how can I check with this?